# After coping Apex application cant access

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

After coping an exsisting application and then trying to run, I'm gettting the following error.

[image: error]

And I have confirmed the security settings are the same in both apps.

This is the working app, 111.
[image: 111]

And this is the one that is not. 110
[image: 110]

Another thing is that I'm not prompted for Log in credentials for app 110, but I get the login prompt for 111.

[image: 111 creds]

[image: 110 creds]

Apex ver 23.1.2

Comment: @Littlefoot I tried that and still get the same error? And I'm not prompted for any creds? Any other Ideas.

Answer (score 1):

- log in to Apex (as a developer)
- go to App Builder, choose application
- go to its Shared Components

  - go to Security

    - Application Access Control - put username into "User Role Assignments"
    - set role to e.g. "Contributor"

That should do; run the application, enter your credentials and - use the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things here.

1. There is **authorization** and **authentication**. authentication is how the user gets access to the application - in your case Oracle APEX Accounts. authorization is what a user can see or do in an application. This is managed by authorization schemes and (optionally) by application access control. The error message you posted states "APEX.AUTHORIZATION.ACCESS_DENIED" (that does say authorization right ?) but you posted the config screens for the authentication... the 2 are NOT THE SAME. The screens you posted have nothing to do with the error message you received in the application.
2. application access control. If you create an application with the feature "application access control", your user gets the "Administration" role by default. That means that you can access any pages you created in that app, including the administration pages.
3. When you copy an application, the roles are copied (those are part of the application) *but the users are not*. This is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/how-access-control-works.htm#HTMDB-GUID-6522AF09-A489-4BA9-B0C5-24457C03729E) (bullet 20.3.1.4) - this isn't the most recent doc but this functionality didn't change. This explains why you don't have access in the newly copied application: the authorization scheme "reader rights" yields false because your user does not exist in the access control metadata for that application. You need to add it manually, as @Littlefoot explained.
4. The "Reader Rights" authorization scheme has caching set to "once per session" (by default). So if you don't have access and you add yourself to the builder... you'll only have access in a new apex session - not in the existing session. Make sure you log out and back it to get access as a reader.